# Converting the result of a MySQL table as per requirement

Tags: mysql, row, rds

The mysql table we work on has data in the following format:

```
    entityId    status    updated_date
    -------------------------------
      1          1        29/05/2017 12:00 
      1          2        29/05/2017 03:00
      1          3        29/05/2017 07:00
      1          4        29/05/2017 14:00
      1          5        30/05/2017 02:00
      1          6        30/05/2017 08:00
      2          1        31/05/2017 03:00
      2          2        31/05/2017 05:00
      .
      .
```

So every entity id has 6 statuses, and every status has an update datetime. Each status has an activity attached to it.
For example  1 - Started journey
             2 - Reached first destination
             3 - Left Point A, moving towards B. etc

I need to get an output in the below format for specific entity id eg 3 and 4. I need the time for status 3 and 4 independently.

```
  entity_id   time_started_journey   time_reached_first_destination
           (update time of status 3)   (update time of status 4)
  --------------------------------------------------------------
      1       29/05/2017 7:00         29/05/2017 14:00   
      2       30/05/2017 7:00         30/05/2017 16:00
```

Later I need to calculate the total time which would be the difference of the two.

How can I achieve the desired result using mysql.

I tried using `Union` operator but cannot do it separate columns.
Also, tried using case `when operator` with the below query but failed.

```
 select distinct entityid,
 (case status when 3 then freight_update_time else 0 end) 
 as starttime,
 (case status when 4 then freight_update_time else 0 end) as endtime
 from table ;
```

Can anyone throw light on this?

Comment: You're on the right track with the case expressions, but you'll need to use aggregation (GROUP_CONCAT specifically) instead of DISTINCT, and have the case's else be `else null` (aggregations typically ignore null). As far as the time difference issue, you will need to convert your date strings to proper date values; then you can use MySQL's built in date functions.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional aggregation is one way to return a resultset that looks like that.

```
 SELECT t.entityid
      , MAX(IF(t.status=3,t.updated_date,NULL)) AS time_started_journey
      , MAX(IF(t.status-4,t.updated_date,NULL)) AS time_reached_first_destination
   FROM mytable t
  WHERE t.status IN (3,4)
  GROUP BY t.entityid 
  ORDER BY t.entityid
```

This is just one suggestion; the specification is unclear about what the query should do with duplicated status values for a given entityid.

There are other query patterns that will return similar results.

Answer (score 1):

My query in MySQL

```
SELECT
    e3.updated_date AS sta3,
    e4.updated_date AS sta4
FROM
    `prueba` AS e3
LEFT JOIN prueba AS e4
ON
    e3.entityId = e4.entityId AND e4.status = 4
WHERE
    e3.status = 3
```

OUTPUT:

[image: result screenshot]